# Python Reportlab Table

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to create a pdf file with a list of items in the form of table. This is my code so far.

```
def GeneratePDF():
        def coord(x, y, unit=1):
            x, y = x * unit, (y * unit)+440-(pdf_temp2)
            return x, y
        width, height = A4
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styleN = styles["BodyText"]
        styleN.alignment = TA_LEFT
        styleBH = styles["Normal"]
        styleBH.alignment = TA_CENTER
        pdf_temp2=(len(PDF_DATA))*31
        hTaskNo = Paragraph('''<b>Task No</b>''', styleBH)
        hTaskDescription = Paragraph('''<b>Task Description</b>''', styleBH)
        hTimeTaken = Paragraph('''<b>Time Taken</b>''', styleBH)
        hName = Paragraph('''<b>Name</b>''', styleBH)
        hSignature = Paragraph('''<b>Signature</b>''', styleBH)
        hDate = Paragraph('''<b>Date</b>''', styleBH)
        hRemarks = Paragraph('''<b>Remarks</b>''', styleBH)

        data= [[hTaskNo, hTaskDescription,hTimeTaken, hName, hSignature,hDate,hRemarks]]
        for i in range(len(PDF_DATA)):
            data.append(PDF_DATA[i])
        Gx=-(len(data))    
        table = Table(data, colWidths=[1 * cm, 14 * cm, 1.2* cm,2.8* cm, 2.8 * cm,2.3*cm,3*cm])
        table.setStyle(TableStyle([
                           ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(-1,Gx),colors.lightgrey)
                           ]))
        c = canvas.Canvas("myfile.pdf", pagesize=landscape(A4))
        c.setFont("Helvetica",20)
        c.drawString(245,545,"My title")
        c.setFont("Helvetica",13)
        c.drawString(36,515,"My description")
        c.drawString(400,515,str(gw_value3))
        table.wrapOn(c, width, height)
        table.wrapOn(c, width, height)
        table.drawOn(c, *coord(1.1, 1, cm))
        c.save()
```

`PDF_DATA` is a list that contains all my information for table.And this list will have different length every time.

When this list is getting too long, the table eventually extend more than the length of the paper without actually creating a new table in next page.

Is there any command i can use so that it will create the rest of the table contents in the next page if the current page is full.

I am aware of `canv.showPage()` . Is that the only command I can use?

Comment: Instead of doing layout yourself you could use the Platypus layout engine. You can create a custom layout with page templates, then it will take care of flowing tables onto next pages.

Comment: @G Gordon Worley III is there any good tutorial on platypus that you know of?

Comment: not that i know of. just the user guide, which will get you started but is occasionally confusing or wrong.